# Duplicate values doing Asynctask in Listview

Tags: android

I have an AsyncTask that connects to a service and with an adapter set the result in a ListView. In the action bar I want to put a button to do the refresh action but the problem is that when I click this button and I call to the service it duplicates the results in the list view.

I have tried:

```
ListView myList=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
            myList.setAdapter(null);
             if ((new Utils(this)).isConnected()){
                    new MyTask().execute();

                }
```

My AsyncTask code:

```
private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                // Showing progress dialog
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MyActivity.this);
                pDialog.setMessage("searching...");
                pDialog.setCancelable(false);
                pDialog.show();
            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                // Creating service handler class instance
                ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

                // Making a request to url and getting response
                String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url+id, ServiceHandler.GET);

                Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

                if (jsonStr != null) {
                    try {
                        JSONArray jsonObj = new JSONArray(jsonStr);

                        // looping through All Contacts
                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonObj.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject c = jsonObj.getJSONObject(i);

                            String nick = c.getString("nick");
                            String minuto = c.getString("minuto");
                            String fecha = c.getString("fecha");

                            // tmp hashmap for single contact
                            HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

                            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value


                            contact.put("nick", nick);
                            contact.put("minuto", minuto);
                            contact.put("fecha", fecha);

                            // adding contact to contact list
                            contactList.add(contact);
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
                }

                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                // Dismiss the progress dialog
                if (pDialog.isShowing())
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                /**
                 * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                 * */
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        DetallePelicula.this, contactList,
                        R.layout.list_rowopiniones, new String[] { "nick", "minuto",
                                "fecha" }, new int[] { R.id.title,
                                R.id.minuto, R.id.fecha });

                ListView myList=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);


                myList.setAdapter(adapter);



            }
        }
```

Somebody can help me? thanks

Comment: Post the bit of code where you set the new values to the ListView please.

Comment: Try to remove all the datas from you array values with clear() method

Comment: I have updated my question with my AsyncTask

Comment: As mentioned by @rogue, you need to clear the `contactList`, otherwise it will just add to the old list. I would suggest, in `onPreExecute`, you write `contactList.clear()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `doInBackground`, you are adding the new data to an already existing list. This means that, as you've mentioned, the data will duplicate.

Just add `contactList.clear()` to your `onPreExecute` method:

```
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            contactList.clear(); // Add this line

            // Showing progress dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MyActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("searching...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }
```